# Dvertx.runArgs cannot be read as VM Options in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vert.x

I want to deploy as Application in Intellij because I can easily debug the app. But, when I want to add VM options, the options cannot be read by the application.

In Run/Debug Configurations, deploy as Application, Main class value is below

```
io.vertx.core.Launcher
```

VM Options

```
-Dvertx.runArgs="-cluster -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Program Arguments

```
run io.vertx.book.message.HelloConsumerMicroservice
```

In above configurations, I am able to run the app and debug it, but when I want to consume Infinispan deployed by another instance I got error

```
No handlers for address
```

If I deployed my application from terminal using

```
mvn compile vertx:run -Dvertx.runArgs="-cluster -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

I succeeded consuming the message.

What do I have to do to get equivalent mvn compile above and apply it to Run as Application?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VM options should be:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

And program arguments:

```
run io.vertx.book.message.HelloConsumerMicroservice -cluster
```

When you set `vertx.runArgs` on the command line, you are configuring the Vert.x Maven plugin, not the `Launcher` itself.